# Using C# params with serilog

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, parameters, optional-parameters, serilog

Just starting using Serilog + ElasticSearch and was wondering if there is an elegant way to log a `params` object array in one log entry.  So far the only way I have been able to manage it is looping through each `params` which creates a separate log entry for each one. Any way to combine them into one log entry?

Thanks!

Sample:

```
public static void MethodEntry<T>(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    if (parameters.Length > 0)
        foreach (var param in parameters) // Will create parameters.Length number of log entries
            Log.ForContext(typeof(T)).Debug("Entering {MethodName} with {@Param}", methodName, param);
    else
        Log.ForContext(typeof(T)).Debug("Entering {MethodName}", methodName);
}
```

EDIT:

Sinks used:

- Serilog
- Serilog.Sinks.Elasticsearch (which includes The File, PeriodicBatching, & RollingFile Sinks)
- Couple Enrichers like Environment and ThreadId

Comment: Have you tried to just past parameters to Log? Something like the following: `Log.ForContext(typeof(T)).Debug("Entering {MethodName} with {@Parameters}", methodName, parameters);` ?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov I did try that, but it resulted in the memory usage spiking until crash with no log entries written.

Comment: How many parameters do you pass?

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov In the crash's case it was 2 (it was an event so `object sender` and `EventArgs e`)

Comment: Which sinks do you use? Please add the initial config of the Serilog

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Updated post.  Mostly just Serilog + ElasticSearch sink, which comes with File, PeriodicBatching, & RollingFile sinks.

Comment: I have tried writing Log with `Log.ForContext(typeof(T)).Debug("Entering {MethodName} with {@Parameters}", methodName, parameters);` with RollingFile sink and it works ok for me. I think the problem is in your sink.

Comment: What object were passed in with `params`?

Comment: http://take.ms/uq4Dw

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov Interesting, it seems to be because my `sender` object is in a very big enterprise app, and thus this `sender` object is massive with a ton of nested stuff.  It crashes trying to parse it all.  It was able to get your example to work too, but the `sender` object was so much smaller.

Comment: Using `@Parameters` will recursively serialize the parameter values, hence the memory usage spike :-). The same code would work without the `@`, I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you know the specific type of your Sender object you can use the following feature of Serilog to avoid logging of the not required information:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Destructure.ByTransforming<YOUR_SENDER_TYPE>(
        r => new { firstValue = r.firstValue, secondValue = r.secondValue })
    .WriteTo ....
```

More about logging structured data you can find in the official documentation [Serilog Structured Data](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/Structured-Data)

Comment: Interesting! My only concern is isn't `sender` in events in .NET always just a generic `object`? Then the override would apply to all `object`s instead of just the `sender` one...

Comment: Yeah that's why I have started my answer from "If you know the specific type". For example when you do a button click as sender there is boxed "Button" object so the checking `is Button` will return true.

Comment: Gotcha, still `Destructure` is great to know so thanks! If there's not specific answer for Event `sender` then I will accept this one in a day or too.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static void MethodEntry<T>(string methodName, params object[] parameters)
{
    Log.ForContext<T>()
        .ForContext("Parameters", parameters)
        .Debug("Entering {MethodName}", methodName);
}
```

This should do what you're after.

Comment: I tried this way with the following objects: `Dim testStr = "test"` & `Dim testObj = New With {Key .Name = "Test", .Price = 1.29}`.  The log entry is not written at all, no crash or exception just seems to skip the call.  Call: `_logger.MethodEntry(NameOf(TestMethod), testStr, testObj)` Method: `log.ForContext("Parameters", parameters).Debug("Entering {MethodName}", methodName);` where `parameters` is `params object[] parameters`.  Any thoughts?

Comment: I'm still having issues with this, any thoughts?

Comment: Do you have `Debug`-level logging turned on? One thing to check.

Comment: Yes, I did check that to make sure I wasn't going crazy haha